# Iterate on object attributes with '$'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this object

```
$scope.stuff = {
  '$X': [],
  '$Y': [],
  '$Z': [],
};
```

And the following HTML

```
<span ng-repeat="(attr, val) in stuff">{{attr}}, {{val}}</span>
```

But the ng repeat doesn't produce anything. If however I delete the '$' from the attribute names - it works. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6266) on GitHub. The developers are aware of this problem and there's debate as to whether or not this should be fixed.